# How to show list of installed/loaded varnish vmod's names in command line?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, varnish

I installed varnish 4.1 and compiled some vmods in a linux (ubuntu14 and centos7).  Now I want to check list of installed vmod or loaded vmod to check if they are properly installed, recognized properly by varnish and loaded. I'm aware that `# ls -al /usr/lib/varnish/vmods` command will list up the vmod files but this does not make sure the vmods are installed/loaded successfully.

While I search varnish reference I found a [varnish-counter field](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnish-counters.html) called vmods, but it is to show the total number of loaded vmods in varnishstat, and not shows vmods by names. Also, varnishstat command is not suitable for this use case as the command is intended to display one time in stdout, and not keep real time update as varnishstats does.

How to compose command to show list of varnish vmods by names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing loaded vmods is not supported. I suggest you file a bug asking for this, or to get it exposed through the `varnishstat` interfaces.  (`varnishstat` can be run in oneshot mode by adding the `-1` flag.)